# Dynamic if statement in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I have a function that looks through arrays and returns ether true or false and will change a global variable to the number that it found if it was above 0. I want to have a if statement that changes so if it is that number it'll call a different function based on that number without having multiple if statements. **So something like**

```
if(left == true){
    for(i=1;i<8;i++){
        if(leftnumber == i){
            //function based on i
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just pass the function an argument?

Comment: Why don't you just make the function dynamic instead of the condition? Btw, what is the function and what does it do?

Comment: I think you search for the switch statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an object to lookup a function based on the number.

```
// object that stores functions based on "leftnumber"
var fnTable = { };

// when "leftnumber" is 6, this function will be called
fnTable[ 6 ] = function() { ... };

// ... for loop stuff

// attempt to find the function for the value at i
var lookup = fnTable[ i ];

// if it exists, call it
if (lookup)
    lookup( );
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
function myfunction(number){
    //do stuff
}

if(left == true){
    for(i=1;i<8;i++){
        if(leftnumber == i){
            myfunction(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or simple: `if(left){ myfunction(leftnumber); }`